# NestJS reload after file change painfully slow

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, webpack, nestjs

I am trying to setup docker to work with NestJS(and TypeScript) with Hot Reload module and its working but after every file change it restarts the whole NestJS server and recompile everything and because of that it takes around 30-40sec for each file change.

I think the problem is because NestJS server restarts every time when it detects file change and instead of just recompile the changed file it restarts the whole server and then recompiles everything. What can I do to speed it up ?

My current files and scripts:

in `package.json` I run `start:dev` script:

`"start:dev": "nest start --webpack --webpackPath webpack-hmr.config.js --watch --tsc",`

My `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: your_username
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: your_password
      POSTGRES_DB: your_database_name
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  app:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    command: npm run start:dev
    ports:
      - 3000:3035
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ../src:/home/node/app
```

`tsconfig.json` :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  },
  "watchOptions": {
    // Use native file system events for files and directories
    "watchFile": "priorityPollingInterval",
    "watchDirectory": "dynamicprioritypolling",
    // Poll files for updates more frequently
    // when they're updated a lot.
    "fallbackPolling": "dynamicPriority",
    // Don't coalesce watch notification
    "synchronousWatchDirectory": true,
    // Finally, two additional settings for reducing the amount of possible
    // files to track  work from these directories
    "excludeDirectories": ["**/node_modules", "dist", "test"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to insert Docker into this workflow, or can you use Node directly without Docker?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes because its easier to manage and updated services later on in production

Comment: An approach I've found successful is to do day-to-day development and unit testing without Docker, and then build containers for integration tests and deployment.  If you're using, for example, a local Node, then you don't need to fight against Docker's filesystem isolation; but once you think your application does fundamentally work, you can build an image and run end-to-end and manual tests.  It seems like that approach might work better with tools like hot reloaders that do not expect to be in an isolated environment.